# Complex Conjugate Of A Function

Tags: complex-numbers, inner-products

I have $f:[-3,3]\to \mathbb{C}$ and $\langle f,g\rangle=\int_{-3}^{3}f(x)\overline{g(x)}dx$

So $\langle x^2,x+x^3\rangle=\int_{-3}^{3}=x^2\cdot (x-x^3)dx?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It's $\int_{-3}^3x^2(x+x^3)\,\mathrm dx$.

Comment: Why isn't  $\overline{g(x)}=-x-x^3?$

Comment: @gbox I was wrong. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Why is that? as we have no complex numbers? the $x$'s only get real number from $[3,-3]$?

Comment: @gbox Since $x\in\mathbb R$, $x+x^3\in\mathbb R$ and therefore $\overline{x+x^3}=x+x^3$.